# Temporary files being created by cron

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I've noticed that within my user's directory (`/home/user/`) there are a bunch of files like....

```
index.html.25
index.html.17
index.html.23
index.html.5
index.html.9
index.html.1
index.html.32
index.html.4
```

And also other files that happen to be the name of my crons that run.  I've verified that these files have no contents in them.  Their file size is 0.

My crons use `wget [url]`

The thing is, none of these crons use my index page (which is PHP, not html).

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Absolutely no idea without more information. Have you something that makes a copy? A backup? A diff? Or whatever?

Comment: I'm not sure what other information I can provide... all of the cron commands merely perform SQL interactions, nothing is echoed on them at all or writes any files.

Comment: maybe the url is not ok and the page redirects to a index.html, did you try to run these `[url]` manually see where they go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
wget -O ${SOME_NAME} ${url}
```

this will replace any existing file if exists

or if you don't need to write into disk

```
wget -q -O- ${url}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot.... I didn't realize `wget` actually got the contents of the destination and recorded an output.  Good call!